# 2nd screen resolution beginner

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I just started using Ubuntu and I've been having an issue setting up my displays.

I'm using an XPS-15-9570 laptop connected to Sceptre 24 Inch 1080P 75Hz LED Monitor via HDMI cable.

bought from this link:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01HIA63AU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HIA63AU)

Here is a picture as a reference for the size:[image]

By default, my laptop display resolution is set to 3840x2160 and it looks fine.
However, there when I connect to my second display via HDMI, everything gets too zoomed in on my laptop display. It seems like the problem is my laptop is way too high resolution and seems bigger than my second monitor, even though my second monitor is bigger.

So as a solution, I set both resolutions to 1920 x 1080 so that they are considered the same size. Everything looks fine now. Except now the problem is when I unplug the HDMI cable, my laptop display now zooms out too much.

I was thinking this might be because the laptop is supposed to be used at 3840x2160 resolution as it originally was intended for, instead of the 1920 x 1080 that I changed the resolution to. So I was wondering if I can just set the second and first display resolutions both to 3840x2160 but on the drop-down menu for the second display, the highest resolution possible is 1920 x 1080.

Another weird thing is that sometimes my displays are fine with 1920 x 1080 resolution but this only occurs sometimes, and it's annoying to have to configure the displays each time I plug in and out of the HDMI.

Here is the dropdown for my laptop screen (has the 3840x2160 resolution option):

[image]

Here is the dropdown for my 2nd display screen (DOES NOT have the 3840x2160 resolution option):

[image]

How do I enable 3840x2160 resolution on my second screen? Is this the correct way to resolve the issue of my laptop screen not scaling correctly when connecting to a bigger display?

I looked around for similar questions and answers but it seemed like the OPs already knew some parts of modifying display settings so I was confused. An answer with step-by-step instructions so that a beginner like me could fully understand would be appreciated. If you could explain the different parts of the system that we are editing, why, and explain any concepts as well, that would be awesome. Please correct me if I am misunderstanding the problem or anything else.

Thanks!

Here is the system information for reference:
[image]

Comment: You can't set the 1080p external monitor to 4K resolution because it's a 1080p monitor.  The image you posted of both displays looks fine.  What's the problem?

Comment: @Nmath for some reason like I wrote above, the display gets super zoomed in or out sometimes when I disconnect or connect my HDMI.

Comment: @Nmath yeah that's the thing I'm confused about. My laptop display is physically smaller but higher resolution than my 2nd display. The problem seems to be solved for some reason but I'm still curious as to how to enable higher-res for 2nd display. or is that impossible since my second display is 1080p max?

Comment: "*is that impossible since my second display is 1080p max?*"  You got it.